# Is there a way to save all the previous iterations of my loop to a single variable in Python?

Tags: python, matlab

I am a MATLAB user who has previously migrated to Python for its flexibility and I am still learning about the syntax and how variable types work. Normally (in MATLAB), I would use a structure array to organize all my image processing data as I perform operations on the image directory I created.

This is how I did it in MATLAB:

```
tiff = dir('*.tiff');
for a = 1 : length(tiff)
    tiff(a).DN = imread(tiff(a).name);
    tiff(a).DN = double(tiff(a).DN);
    tiff(a).C = ((tiff(a).DN).*0.04)-273.15;
    tiff(a).F = ((tiff(a).C).*1.8)+32;
end
```

I have already made an image directory using:

```
imgs = []
path = 'path of image files'
valid_images = [".tiff"]
for f in os.listdir(path):
    ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in valid_images:
        continue
    imgs.append(Image.open(os.path.join(path, f)))
```

and I can loop through to show my thermal images while editing them to change from digital number to Fahrenheit using:

```
images_C = []
images_F = []
images = []

for n in range(0, 18):
    images = np.asarray(imgs[n])
    images_C = ((images * 0.04) - 273.15)
    images_F = (images_C * 1.8) + 32

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(images_F, cmap="gray")
    ax.axis('off')
    if n > 18:
        break
```

However, it only saves the final iteration to the variable "images_C" and "images_F" while I'd like the variables to a new column of the variable "imgs" each time I iterate (like MATLAB) or have some other way to keep track of all the images' data throughout the iterations. This is just a test run and I'll need to be able to do this and more with 1000+ images in the future. It just seems like I can go a lot faster with MATLAB right now or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Very important to understand, **python doesn't have variable types**. It is a dynamically typed language. Of course, it is *strongly typed* so *objects* have a type.

Comment: `images_C = ((images * 0.04) - 273.15)` just assigns a `np.ndarray` object to the variable `images_C`, this will never affect the empty list, `images_C = []` that you assign to that variable before the loop. Stop thinking in terms of "variables". There are objects and you can do operations on those objects.

Comment: if `imgs` are all the same shape, you could preallocate `images` as a 3D numpy array and do all the C/F conversion as matrix operations